# -Layout breaks when TextView is too long

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm using `RecyclerView` with `ConstrainLayout` to list all files like this

[image: Click me]

But somehow the space between the first line and the second line is increased when the text is long (the above picture). I don't know exactly what is the problem. Here is my code:

**item.xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/layoutItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_folder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtLastModified"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgFile"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLastModified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgFile"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFileName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAdditionalInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLastModified"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtLastModified"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtLastModified" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Bonus:**

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:maxLines="1"` for the `textview` 'txtFileName'